# Print invoice that show newly added data from database to crystal report with unique invoice number

Tags: c#, database, crystal-reports

I want to make an invoice that prints the newly added data in database with unique invoice number using crystal report in C#.
Can anyone help me or suggest me the best tutorial. I searched the YouTube but can't find the solution...

Comment: The question is too generic. Provide some sample code so that it will help others to provide relevant solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Create trigger in your database for capturing new added data (inserts) in your target tables.
You can store all captured data to specific table which you create in your database with unique ID. Than use that data for generating invoice with crystal report.

Comment: I did the same thing my table has unique id of data. but i didn't know how to fetch that newly added to crystal report. crystal report show the all data that are in table.

Comment: You can capture new added data to new table using trigger and than you have everything you want in your new created table. Is this not enough ?

Comment: I did this but not print the data on crystal report

Comment: Could you please provide your part of code that you use for print data with crystal report ?

Comment: Check this link for create crystal report https://tutorialslink.com/Articles/Create-Sales-Invoice-Report-using-Crystal-Report-in-C-windows-application/55

Comment: yes i check this, but in this they use 3 tables that i didn't understand because i want to show data from one table only of database.that's why i asked for help